# How to set QCamera on label

Tags: qt, camera, label, qgraphicsview

I've decided no to use OpenCV. I will use the QCamera class. Everything is working perfect to this moment. I can capture and save images wherever I want, but the problem is how I can set the camera to a label or graphics view?

I mean, to see what is happening at the moment. When I make infinite loop everything crashes. Write any information you know, cause there are no examples how to do that, or I just can't see. If you can please write some source code.

Comment: "Write any information you know"... eh that's going to take a while given the hundreds of thousands of SO users and the average amount of knowledge a human being has... Please show the relevant parts of the code you have that is "crashing", and explain exactly what "crashing" means (what behavior you see) so that people can help you fix it.

Comment: void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked() //start capturing
{
    camera->start();

    while(1){
        camera->searchAndLock();
        imageCapture->capture(imagePath);
        ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap(imagePath));
        camera->unlock();
    }


}

Comment: Never use infinite loop with Qt. Use events instead. [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtimer.html) is most probably what you need.

Comment: @user2521257: please [edit] your post to add the code in there. (Take care to format it as code, read the editor help for guidance.) Never post code in comments, it's unreadable.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me.I will see what i can do now.Roku i was not pretty sure to this moment is there a problem to use infinite loop in QT, but  now i know.There is always problem with the infinite loop in QT.

Answer (score 2):

Use `QCameraVievFinder` or `QVideoWidget` widgets ( docs - [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qcameraviewfinder.html))  for that purpose, here is example for you:

```
#include <QCameraViewfinder>

// .......   
QCamera *camera=new QCamera(this);
QCameraViewfinder *viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(this);
viewfinder->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Maximum);
camera->setViewfinder(viewfinder);

setCentralWidget(viewfinder);
//viewfinder->show();

camera->start(); // to start the viewfinder
```

Note: you need to add to your *,pro file this config to use them: `QT  +=  multimedia multimediawidgets`

If you want a bit more low level widget (to process every frame the way you like (face detection etc), subclass `QAbstractVideoSurface`, docs - [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qabstractvideosurface.html)
or try to connect to `QVideoProbe` class (docs - [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qvideoprobe.html)), though i could not do it myself, this class is a bit experimental i guess, didn't worked

Comment: Shf, thanks for the answer.I 've heard about QCameraViewFinder before but i didn't read anything.Now i will look what i can do with it.Thanks

Comment: @user2521257 glad to be helpfull, upvote & accept if it solves your problem

Comment: After this day, my problem with the camera was totally solved.There are no more problems.Now i will continue my GUI project thanks to all of you guys.After 1-2 months i will start searching for how to write printer driver ;), but however.Thanks too all again. ;)